# how to import min files with webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to import a third party min js and min css from a folder with webpack, but I can not find this folder with webpack.

My structure is

```
-node_modules
-src
-lib
  -min.js
  -css
    -min.css
```

But I can not recognize this lib folder. I tried alias on my webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'lib': './lib/'
    }
  },
```

I tried resolve.modules:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "lib")],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    }
  },
```

But did not work as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to reference those files in one of your `*.js` files that already is in bundle.

Assuming the following structure:

```
-node_modules

-src
    -app.js

-lib
  -min.js
  -css
    -min.css
```

and the entry point of your project is `./src/app.js`, add these 2 lines of code there:

**app.js:**

```js
import { min } from '../lib/min.js'
import '../lib/css/min.css'
```

That's it! Webpack will take care of those library and stylesheet.
If you need to know more about required *webpack loaders* and how to extract style file, refer to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376808/using-webpack-2-and-extract-text-webpack-plugin/45176412#45176412).